# Regex to match either 0-9 digits of any length or exact string N/A

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a text field which should be entering either 0-9 characters or exact string N/A.
I am using this regex: /[\d]|\bN/A\b/
But this is not matching what I want:

What I Want is:

1. 123534 - Match
2. N/A - Match
3. N/AN/A - no match
4. N - no match
5. NA - no match
6. N/A1234 - no match
7. 134234N/A - no match
8. 1234N - no match

My current regex /[\d]|\bN/A\b/ is matching above 6, 7 and 8 case which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regex: `^(\d+|N\/A)$`

Comment: how to write a regex that matches either small letter a-z or 0-9 digits in any order or N/A. Ex.          
       1. asdf234 - Match                                                                                                      
       2. 676897hkjk - Match                                                                                             
       3. N/A - match                                                                                                         
       4. N/Aertg - no match

Comment: can you give a couple of example strings to be matched?